# Get specific part of website in c#

Tags: c#

I'm making an online dictionary application in Windows. The app has a search bar for looking up the word, and the panel that contains the definition of that word.
I know how to search but I don't know how to get specific part of the web.

For example: [Lose - Từ điển](http://dict.laban.vn/find?type=1&query=lose)

And I only want to get the part of definition of the word:

[image: Image here]

How can I do this in c#?

Comment: Which specific part of the contents in the image are you interested in extracting?

Comment: The image is the part of the site, and that is the part I want to extract from the site

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial on extracting information from HTML: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/804660/How-to-Parse-HTML-using-Csharp